# Failed to find data source: org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RestDataSource

Tags: api, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using Rest Data Source and I keep running into an issue with the output saying the following:

```
hope_prms = { 'url' : search_url
            , 'input' : 'new_view'
            , 'method' : 'GET'
            , 'readTimeout' : '10000'
            , 'connectionTimeout' : '2000'
            , 'partitions' : '10'}
sodasDf = spark.read.format('org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RestDataSource').options(**hope_prms).load()
An error occurred while calling o117.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RestDataSource. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:649)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

I've built my jar file and the class is in the directory so I'm not sure why it's still failing.

In our cluster it's shows the following:

```
sodasDf = spark.read.format('org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RestDataSource').options(**hope_prms).load()
  File "/app/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 172, in load
  File "/app/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/app/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/app/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o109.load.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 9.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 9.0 (TID 12, cvglpcdh13.td.afg, executor 4): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: it seems spark cannot find the jar. You should add it to spark-submit --jars <RestDataSpource.jar>

Comment: Hi, I have spark-submit --jar <RestDataSource.jar> I'm not sure why it's still failing.

Comment: In the Yarn client it is picking up the jar file but it will eventually fail.

Uploading resource file:/home/mseyal/spark-datasource-rest_2.11-2.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -> hdfs://kvop-gap/user/this_user/.sparkStaging/application_1600585513410_11654/spark-datasource-rest_2.11-2.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: updated here is there error from our cluster:

sodasDf = spark.read.format('org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RestDataSource').options(**expert_prms_Soda).load()
  File "/app/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 172, in load
  File "/app/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__

java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RESTRelation$$anonfun$3.apply(RestRelation.scala:108)